# Sim toolkit is missing after upgrade os to Android 5.0.2

Tags: cyanogenmod

I've upgraded my OnePlus One to 5.0.2 (CyanogenMod), but the Sim Toolkit app is missing.

Can anyone help to solve this problem, because I need this feature for mobile banking?

Comment: Check whether if it is hidden from launcher.

Comment: What Network are you on?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I found it out to work. Create a SIM-PIN in your settings, restart the phone with the PIN, and you will have the toolkit in your app browser.

Answer (score 0):

Please use your SIM with this toolkit as a first SIM (SIM1). Otherwise PIN code popup might not pop up. In my case switching SIMs helped.